# Can someone help me with this problem with python and google sheets api?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

#### Problem

I am testing out google sheets and trying to make a filter that deletes all Representatives, leaving only Senators on the sheet. I am using the info in this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ASDBcPDu5xT1key0BsszpAFL_34mt0HTBN3fNwL-KjE/edit#gid=2063166065):

#### Code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("Congress").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()  # Get a list of all records

rowCount = sheet.row_count

val = sheet.col_values(1)


i = 1
for value in val:
    if value == 'rep':
        print('Deleted:', sheet.cell(i,1).value, sheet.cell(i,5).value)
        sheet.delete_row(i)
    i = i +1
```

I am getting:

```
Deleted: rep Young
Deleted: rep Roby
Deleted: rep Aderholt
Deleted: rep Palmer
Deleted: sen Jones
Deleted: rep Crawford
Deleted: rep Womack
```

It basically only deletes the ones I bolded below:

[image: Deleting]

It's supposed to delete all the rows that have 'rep', but it ends up not deleting all of them and it deletes some that have 'sen' too. 
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting rows while you iterate over them. The remaining rows get shifted up - that messes with your indexing - you skip some rows and delete others:

Example:

```
line 0   rep     someone
line 1   rep     someone
line 2   sen     someone
```

You for loop over your lines:
- you test line 0 , you delete line 0, line 1 becomes line 0
- you test line 1 next - all dandy it is a `sen`
- you skipped the (originally 1, now 0 line)

etc.

---

Delete from the back instead:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("Congress").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()  # Get a list of all records

rowCount = sheet.row_count

val = sheet.col_values(1)

for idx,value in reversed(list(enumerate(val,1))):
    if value == 'rep':
        print('Deleted:', sheet.cell(idx,1).value, sheet.cell(idx,5).value)
        sheet.delete_row(idx)
```